# How to run the examples in OpenGL Programming Guide on Mac with Xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL programming with the book OpenGL Programming Guide. But I cannot run the examples in the book with my Macbook. There are always dozens of errors when running even dealing with the first example Triangles. I wonder what should I do to run the examples in Red Book with Xcode.

[Platform Information]
Macbook Air, OS X 10.10, Xcode 6.1

[What did I try]
1. I deleted AppDelegate.* and main.m, and then create a cpp file triangles.cpp and copy the source code into it.(The source code will be attached at the end)
2. I added OpenGL.framework.
3. I manually installed glew, and added corresponding paths to Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths. And added -lGLEW to Other Linker Flags.
4. I manually installed freeglut, added corresponding paths to Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths, and added -lGLUT to Other Linker Flags, just under the instruction of Lazy Foo's OpenGL tutorial.
5. I added the directory of the source code attached to the Red Book into Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths so Xcode can find "vgl.h" and "LoadShaders.h". And LoadShaders.cpp was added to the project.

The reason I did step 3 and 4 is to make compiling succeed, otherwise, I would receive lots of errors such as :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_glutInitContextProfile", referenced from:
          _main in main.o
```

In this way, however, the compiling was OK, but there's an error when I run it:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  34 (X_UngrabKey)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

I really wonder what is the right way to run the examples in Red Book on Mac OS X!

triangles.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers};
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0};

GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

void init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        {-0.90, -0.90},
        {0.85, -0.90},
        {-0.90, 0.85},
        {0.90, -0.85},
        {0.90, 0.90},
        {-0.85, 0.90}
    };

    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
        {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert"},
        {GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag"},
        {GL_NONE, NULL}
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    if(glewInit())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind working in C# then look into [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com), it's an OpenGL wrapper for Mono and .Net. I haven't tried it with Xcode, but it works beautifully in Xamarin Studio.

If you go the Xamarin route, there are two options:

1) Download [the latest OpenTK release](http://www.opentk.com/files/download-opentk.html) and reference `OpenTK.dll`
2) Use the OpenTK included with Xamarin, instructions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/platform-features/opentk/).

I'd recommend downloading the external version, there are loads of helpful examples included.

Something to watch out for however is that on MacOS, the GameWindow constructor defaults to OpenGL 2.1 (doesn't on Windows), so if you want to use modern features you must explicitly specify the OpenGL version number in the constructor.

```
public Game() : base(800, 600, new GraphicsMode(new ColorFormat(8), 3, 3, 4), "Welcome To Hell", GameWindowFlags.Default, DisplayDevice.Default, 3, 0, GraphicsContextFlags.Default)
{
}
```

The Red Book examples won't run directly in OpenTK, but the GL calls are the same, the syntax just needs modifying. I found [Neo Kabuto](http://neokabuto.blogspot.com.au/p/tutorials.html)'s blog the best for OpenTK tutorials, and after no time at all, you'll be able to re-write the Red Book code in TK.

This probably wasn't the answer you were looking for, but it's how I solved the problem.